# Problems with normals

Tags: modeling

I make a post-ussr apartment building with interior and I have some problems with normals. When I import in unity the model, some parts are missing. I recalculated normals inside and outside but it is not work.[image: here is the picture with fliped and recalculated normals]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

If recalculation does not work, it means the topology of your model is not good and Blender is not able to decide what is supposed to be inside and what outside of your model. You have two options:

- Either you care about the topology of your model and you'll have to correct it (ideally close the model so that it creates an enclosed volume). After that the recalculation should work as it is supposed to
- Or you do not care about the topology and you can flip the faces by hand. You can do that by selecting red faces in the edit mode Alt+N -> Flip

Comment: BTW. The flipped parts in Unity are not gone. They are physically there, but backface culling is on by defualt and you can see them only from the front facing side